# In flutter,how to jump to a specified screen(not main screen) after clicking on received background push notification(Foreground mode is ok!)?

Tags: flutter

As title, In flutter,how to redirect to a specified screen(not main scrren) after clicking on received background push notification?

PS: Foreground mode is ok!

Pls see my code, after I listened background message,then...what should I do next?

The following is my main.dart code:

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import './tabs.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';

@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  print("Handling a background message: ${message.messageId}");
  print("Handling a background message: ${message.data['id']}");
  print("Handling a background message: ${message.data['screen']}");
}

void main(List<String> args) async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(home: Tabs());
  }
}
// return const MaterialApp(home: Tabs());
```

After clicking on background push notification,jump to a specified screen,not main screen.thanks all.

Comment: Pls explain your needs. It is not clear for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can handle the background message after your flutter app has a context.

here the documentation: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/notifications/#handling-interaction

- handling interaction from background message

```
  Future<void> setupInteractedMessage() async {
    // Get any messages which caused the application to open from
    // a terminated state.
    RemoteMessage? initialMessage =
        await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage();

    // If the message also contains a data property with a "type" of "chat",
    // navigate to a chat screen
    if (initialMessage != null) {
      _handleMessage(initialMessage);
    }

    // Also handle any interaction when the app is in the background via a
    // Stream listener
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen(_handleMessage);
  }
  
  void _handleMessage(RemoteMessage message) {
    if (message.data['type'] == 'chat') {
      Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/chat', 
        arguments: ChatArguments(message),
      );
    }
  }
```

then call the function inside the initState. if your apps has a `SplasScreen`   put the function there. So after the apps initialize, the function will executed before navigate to the mainscreen.

but if you dont have `SplashScree`, you can put it on top of all function inside the `initState` on the `MainScreen`.

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // Run code required to handle interacted messages in an async function
    // as initState() must not be async
    setupInteractedMessage();
  }
```

Comment: If possible, please explain the ChatArguments object you have mentioned.

Comment: its example from the documentation. actually you can create your own object based on your need. also you may use `Navigator.push()` and pass the message as parameter of your screen